# After my laptop is suspended, I can't log in

Tags: login, suspend

I use Ubuntu 15.10 and I have a log in problem.
After I leave my laptop for 10 minutes, it goes into suspended state and when I type in the password it says that the password i have typed is invalid. Everything related to the password field, mouse cursor and graphical environment works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the numlock key on, do you?  No warnings like the caps lock, and on some keyboards, the numbers will replace the letters which produces an invalid password.

Comment: Nope. Something in addition, I have to press "Switch User" in order to login.